# Scan for string across multiple files with R

Tags: r, string, file, csv

I would like to scan multiple files for strings in R and know which file names have that string.

Is there a way to do this with something like grep, cat, readLines in a function maybe?

If I scan the files using:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
```

then maybe something like:

```
for (f in fileNames) {
    stuff <- read.csv(fileName, sep = ",")
    grep("string")

}

names(res) <- substr(filenames, 1, 30)
```

Or maybe even better, a loop like this:

```
for( f in  filenames ){
   cat("string", file=f)
}

for( f in filenames) {
    cat(readLines(f), sep="\n")
}
```

This code doesn't work, I'm just trying to think this through. Im certain there is a better way to do this. It sounds simple but I cant get it right.

I want to scan files for strings and then have the output of the filenames where the string was found. I have not found an example to do this in R.

Suggestions?

Comment: What platform are you running?

Comment: Richard, I'm on Windows. In OSX and Unix, I believe you can use commands to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

note that in your first code example you use `f` as a loop variable while inside the loop you use `fileName` instead (also R is case sensitive so `fileNames` and `filenames` are different objects).

if it's unlikely that your search string contains the CSV delimiter, you can indeed use `readLines(..)` together with `grep(..)`. `grep(..)` then returns a list of line numbers where the string occurs. Try the following code:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")

for (fileName in fileNames) {
   if (length(grep("string", readLines(fileName))) > 0) { print(fileName)}
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: thanks for the hint about the low quality queue ! I improved the 'text to code ratio' and the overall length of the answer

Comment: Andre, this works. Thank you for giving more details. What does the "length" do in the function?

Comment: `grep(..)` either returns a vector of integers (corresponding to the matching lines) or `integer(0)`. Not using `length(..)`, just doing `if (grep(...)) { ...} `, you'll either get an error `argument is of length zero` if there was no match or a warning `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` in case of a match. `length(..)` is essentially returning the number of lines matching.